# IIS where ASP pages aren't working

Tags: iis-6, asp

ASP pages don't seem to be working if they contain any ASP code. Is there a way to test the setup of IIS6?

Comment: Are you talking classic asp or asp.net? If the latter which version?

Comment: You don't happen to use SiteMinder on this server do you?

Comment: Classic ASP, mostly the ASP.NET on the server is working.

Comment: No Siteminder installed here.

Comment: Just FYI - This case wasn't an issue with ASP pages, activity from other processes were killing the server. ASP pages were the first against the wall. Seemingly the rest of the site was working, but these pages turned out to be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the error(s) that you're receiving or symptoms of the problem it's hard to narrow down what you're dealing with and provide a solution.

However, to cover the basics:

- Make sure ASP is installed on your IIS box.  If this is ASP.NET make sure you've installed the proper version of the .NET framework.
- [**Make sure ASP is enabled as a web extension**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737992(WS.10).aspx)
- If this is ASP.NET you can run `aspnet_regiis -i` from the installation folder of the .NET version you're working with to make sure it gets registered with IIS.  The folder you'll want to look in is `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[specific version folder]\`
- Make sure you have configured an application on your web site or in the directory that holds your ASP code.

Comment: All very useful points, thankyou squillman

Answer (score 1):

In IIS on the site, right-click and select Properties.  In the dialog that brings up, select the "Home Directory" tab and click on "Configuration..." and look for what "App Mappings" does the .asp extension have?  Is it "C:\WINNT\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll"?  That is where I'd start for tracking down the problem.

Comment: Thanks - this helps identify that ASP is indeed installed, thanks!